# how to target the element above my show more button

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to target the element above my show more button, so when i click the button more text appears i don't want to target it by class name or id

here is my code

```
<div class="ccontainer" id="ccontainer">
  <p id="context"> content </p>
  <div class="img" id="cntimgcon" >
    <img src="images\image2.jpg" id="cntimgp1">
  </div>
  <p id="context"> content </p>
</div>
<Button id="showmore" onclick=" this.parentElement.style.maxHeight = 'none'"> show more </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't refer to the IDs that can get cumbersome. Instead give your show more button a class to refer to. That will give you the ability to add many to the same page without needing to adjust/track the IDs.

This is a basic example that toggles a class on the content div that will show the full div. Obviously the details are up to your specific needs.

Using **previousElementSibling** allows you to refer to the previous element.

```js
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  let btn = e.target;
  if(btn.className.indexOf("showmore") > -1){
    btn.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.ccontainer{
 height:50px;
 overflow:hidden;
 border:1px solid #000;
 margin:10px 0;
 padding:10px;
}

.ccontainer.active{
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="ccontainer">
  <p id="context"> content </p>
  <div class="img" id="cntimgcon" >
    <img src="images\image2.jpg" id="cntimgp1">
  </div>
  <p id="context"> content </p>
</div>
<Button class="showmore"> show more </button>

<div class="ccontainer">
  <p id="context"> content3 </p>
  <div class="img" id="cntimgcon" >
    <img src="images\image2.jpg" id="cntimgp1">
  </div>
  <p id="context"> content4 </p>
</div>
<Button class="showmore"> show more </button>
```

Comment: @curious, if you are wanting to modify the button itself, in the if statement the variable **btn** is the button you clicked on

Comment: @curious using my code you can try: **btn.parentNode.querySelector(".ccontainer")**

Answer (score 0):

If your using only vanila JS you can access the previous element with the `previousElementSibling` property.

Example:

```
var showMoreButton = document.getElementById('showmore');
var previousElement = showMoreButton.previousElementSibling;
```

Comment: I looks to me you are trying to have some sort of dropdown or collapsible. Is this behaviour what you are trying to do? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery you can use:

```js
$(this).prev();   // $(this) is equal to the button
// or very specific
$(this).prev(".container");
```

Using vanilla JS you could use something like

```html
onclick="this.previousSibling"
```

not sure if vanilla js has a way of selecting a previous node by identifier.
Any whitespace or comment block is also considered a `previousSibling`, so be careful with that.

Comment: Using previousElementSibling solves the whitespace issue

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div>
<div class="ccontainer" id="ccontainer">
  <p id="context"> content </p>
  <div class="img" id="cntimgcon" >
    <img src="images\image2.jpg" id="cntimgp1">
  </div>
  <p id="context"> content </p>
</div>
<Button id="showmore" onclick="hideParent(this)"> show more </button>

</div>
```

js

```
function hideParent(elm){
    console.log(elm.previousElementSibling.innerHTML )
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/rkqnmv0w/